# What is the current state of token verification?

Tags: token

I'm aware that there is a [deprecated list](https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list) of "verified" tokens on github. And that https://explorer.solana.com and https://solscan.io both use this list to show whether a token is verified or not.

So if I launch a token today is there anyway to have it show up as being verified on the explorers?

Comment: Please read the first few lines of the README on the token-list at https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list?tab=readme-ov-file#read-below-for-instructions-on-new-token-metadata-flow and you'll see what you need to do